# why DSolve gives "Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False." when I am not using any assumptions in the call?

Tags: differential-equations

I never seen this before. Solving standard Bessel ode. Why DSolve gives this warning

```
Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False
```

When there are no assumptions used anywhere in the call?

```
ClearAll[x, y]
ode = x^2*y''[x] + x*y'[x] + (x^2 - 5)*y[x] == 0
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

Screen shot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not now have an earlier version to check if this new or been there in earlier version.

Where is this warning coming from?

V 13.01 on windows 10
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caAJi.png

Comment: You're right, it's weird.

Comment: `Block[{DSolve`print = Print}, DSolve[ode, y[x], x]]` shows the message arises in `DSolveSpecialInhomogeneousLinearSecondOrderODE` before that method of solution is rejected. It seems to be a minor coding error(?) in that they failed to check Sqrt[5] was integer before passing that as an assumption to `Simplify`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I ran `Block[{DSolveprint = Print}, DSolve[ode, y[x], x]]` but received no additional information.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You have to decode my rushed comment: ``Block[{DSolve`print = Print}, DSolve[ode, y[x], x]]`` (misformatted, missing backtick) -- the rest of my comment came from rummaging around here and there. E.g. ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@DSolve`DSolveSecondOrderODEDump`DSolveSpecialInhomogeneousLinearSecondOrderODE``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of the internal steps of DSolve is running

```
Simplify[-((
  2^(1 + 1/2 (1 - 2 Sqrt[5]) + 
    1/4 (-1 + Cos[(-1 + 2 Sqrt[5]) \[Pi]])) \[Pi]^(-1 + 
    1/4 (1 - Cos[(-1 + 2 Sqrt[5]) \[Pi]])) x^(1 + Sqrt[5]))/
  Gamma[1/2 + Sqrt[5]]), False]
```

which is where that warning is coming from. Unfortunately the stack trace ends there, so I can't tell where the False in the second argument is coming from.

Comment: So what does False as second argument of Simplify mean?

Comment: It appears that michael-e2 was able to figure out why this assumption came out as False, check the comments above.

Comment: No, I mean Simplify syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Simplify allows you to pass in multiple arguments, in this instance False was passed in as an argument(which Michael-e2 was able to explain how that got there), and having False as an argument makes the whole thing evaluate to False.

Comment: "makes the whole thing evaluate to False" Nope, it gives a function.

Comment: It makes all of Simplify evaluate to False.

Comment: It prints in fact -((2^(1 - Sqrt[5]) x^(1 + Sqrt[5]))/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + Sqrt[5]]))